# Import map to MoJang Minecraft version for Win 10 Beta Testversion

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, windows-10

The test version of Mojang Minecraft version for Windows 10 offers an Option were you can Import maps as .mcworld-files. But looking for such files online keeps returning no results at all. I'm only able to find zip files filled with several types of files (.dat, .mcr, etc.).

Is it possible to import maps at all in this version? If yes, how?

Sorry if it's a stupid question, i'm entirely new to actually playing Minecraft :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the map must be created through the Windows 10 Edition game, where there someone can export their world. Since the feature is so new, map-makers likely just haven't exported and uploaded them yet.

To import them, just click on the import button and navigate to the .mcworld file. The .zip files (and what is within) you are finding are for the Java version, and thus will not work with this edition unless converted (if that is possible).

Welcome to Minecraft!